# jQuery Theme Div borders and the 960 grid system issues

Tags: css, jquery-ui, 960.gs

I'm implementing the [960 grid](http://960.gs/) system on my pre-existing site. I'm using a jQuery theme which means that every div that has content is assigned the class `ui-widget-content` which, as part of the theme, gives it a 1px border. I like this border design since my content divs are white, while my site's background is off white - giving it a nice visual contrast.

The problem I have, however, is that with these 1px borders, I can't fit divs horizontally since they are too big. For example, if I do this:

```
<div class="grid_16 alpha omega">
  <div class="grid_10 alpha ui-widget-content">
    <div class="grid_5 alpha">some stuf...</div>
    <div class="grid_5 omega">some stuf...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_6 omega">
    more stuf...
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the `grid_10` div being too big by 2 pixels and thus, hanging out the end of the `grid_16` div on the far right. I thought I would fix this by creating a new class like so:

```
.border-fix {
    border-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

and then adding that to the `grid_10` div, like so:

```
<div class="grid_16 alpha omega">
  <div class="grid_10 alpha ui-widget-content border-fix">
    <div class="grid_5 alpha">some stuf...</div>
    <div class="grid_5 omega">some stuf...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_6 omega">
    more stuf...
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, however, my two inner `grid_5` divs are being squeezed so that they now sit on top of each other, not side by side since there isn't enough room horizontally (since the `grid_10` div is 2 pixels narrower than it should be with the borders being inside, not outside)

So how do I fix this (or is it fixable)? I like the style of having the border on the div since it separates the content from the background nicely. But, with a border, my div widths are mucked up. I prefer not to force it with an extra column, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740094/jquery-ui-with-960-grid-border-issue).

Any magic tricks I might try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution I believe works that doesn't break the grid system, I don't have to edit any of the div sizes to account for a border, nor do I have to add any wierd margin or padding of 1px. Perhaps this is a bit hacky, but all I did was create a new class like this:

```
.border-fix {
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px grey;
}
```

and added this class to any div that I wanted to have borders. This will override the `ui-widget-conent` class to remove the border and adds a shadow to the box. The design of the shadow I have there says to have a 0px horizontal shift, a 0px vertical shift, and blur the shadow by 3 px. With a color of grey, this looks almost exactly like a normal border without it affecting my div widths.

Again, I think this might be a bit of a hacky way of doing things, but it seems cunningly clever, if I don't say so myself :P

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should not combine other classes with style to containers that are used for the grid to prevent this behaviour. The grid system should be adopted as-is and if you need borders and use different paddings or margins, you should wrap the content inside the grid cell in another div and apply the style to this element - otherwise you will break the grid.

I know this creates extra divs, but it helps having consistent behaviour. If you are using fixed size grids (defined in px instead of %) you can subtract 2px from the width and add 1px border to each cell to even up, so you end up with the same size and same layout.

Comment: Thanks for the comment re not giving container divs style. I'm still new to the grid system and hadn't thought that styling a container would be bad practice. I'll change that and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just redefine the style of grid_10 to be 2 pixels less than before?
(was it 580? 580-2=578)

```
<style>
.grid_10 {width:578px}
</style>

<div class="grid_10 alpha ui-widget-content">
```

Or if you can't redefine it for all the site, just go and see what style are applied to grid_10, clone them in a new style my_smaller_grid_10_with_borders

---

While I'm an this, I still wonder semantically what is the difference between something like this:

```
<div class="grid_16 alpha omega">
    <div class="grid_10 alpha ui-widget-content border-fix">
    <div class="grid_5 alpha">some stuf...</div>
...
```

and something like this:

```
<table><tr><td>some stuf...</td>...
```

What I am saying is that the 960grid system sucks as much as tables sucked. Aren't we supposed to write semantically correct readable documents?

(ok just a digression, hope the solution works)

Comment: Tanks for the comment. I'm hesitant to muck with the px definitions of the grid system just to deal with borders. Instead, I'll do as nxtwrld suggests and not style the container divs. interesting that you think the grid system sucks - to each their own. My original design actually included only tables, no divs. I found that the layout was getting out of hand and too difficult to achieve with tables so I had to move to divs for a proper layout. But that's just me :)

Comment: @Garfonzo haha, no doubt tables sucked :), I was only saying that writing `class="grid_10"` is not that much better than writing `width="580"` in the HTML. The ideal (in an ideal world where browsers just plain worked) would be to write HTML with no info about position and sizes, and handle those in the CSS

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I agree with you, the grid system isn't too much different than just doing `width=580`. However, it's all the other fancy things that make life easy with the grid system. I was finding that building my own CSS structure with pre-defined widths and such wasn't working too smoothly. This 960 grid system, for me, has made aligning things and organizing my pages quite easy and consistent.